# What is this notation? (About polynomials)

Tags: polynomials

I have a question like this:

> Given a polynomial $f$, and a set $F = \{f_1, f_2\}$,
>
> (for example, $f = x^2y + y^2$, and $f_1 = x^2, f_2 = y^2$)
>
> using LEX, compute $\bar f^{(f_1,f_2)} = \_\_\_\_\_\_.$

Any idea what does $\bar f^{(f_1,f_2)}$ mean here?

Does it mean to do the polynomial division first, and then write $f$ in the form of $f = q_1*f_1 + q_2*f_2 + r$ where $r$ is the remainder?

Comment: This looks like nonstandard notation.  There's no way for us to say for sure, you'll just have to consult the source of this problem.

Comment: Solved. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just found it in Chapter 2.6 of this book:

Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, Fourth Edition, 2015
(https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/iva.html)

It means the remainder of the division.